# getting JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl

Tags: java, jvm, websphere, saaj

Im working on upgrade project where moving java web application from java 6 to java 8 in websphere Application server 8.5.

We are using many SOAP web service calls to interact with other internal systems and vendor systems.So now we are getting below error message everytime when system tries to create SOAP request.

```
JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl, method=createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment;, pc=5;
```

> Type Mismatch, argument 0 in signature com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentFragment.:(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/CoreDocumentImpl;)V does not match 
>   Exception Details:
>     Location:
>       com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl.createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment; @5: JBinvokespecial
>     Reason:
>       Type 'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/CoreDocumentImpl'
>     Current Frame:
>       bci: @5
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' }
>       stack: { 'uninitialized', 'uninitialized', 'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' },

As a workaround, we have tried updating jar version to Saaj_impl-1.3.27 but still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

As an off-the-cuff guess, the issue seems like a DOM mix-up between the SAAJ RI and Axis2. Is your app bundling it's own Web Services implementation including SAAJ? You mentioned updating SAAJ to 1.3.27 and the error mentions the SAAJ RI, so if your app has it's own Web Services Implementation than you need to disable the one provided by WebSphere:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html.

You could try to set the following system properties:

```
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl 
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory 
-Djavax.xml.soap.MetaFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl
-Dcom.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true
```

The properties are an example and the fully qualified names of the SAAJ RI may change based on the version of SAAJ you are using.

If your app should be using the WebSphere Web Services Engine can you tell me which version of Java 8 you are on?